# GRUB installation failed 18.04, Dual boot problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have Windows 10 installed, as my main OS and I also want to try installing Ubuntu 18.04 as a secondary option but when I try to install it gives me an error saying **"The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot."** How to fix this issue? I have seen someone suggesting a tutorial [here](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-on-uefi-and-legacy-bios-system.html). But I'm not sure whether it is going to affect the boot of Windows 10 or not, since it is my main OS, I do not want to make any change to it. Just want to try installing Ubuntu manually on a separate partition. Dual booting Windows 10 and Linux Mint (latest version) was not so difficult though. (By the way I'm using Samsung NP300V5A-A07IN laptop that was manufactured around 2011 or so, not sure about that, and I also have no idea whether it has a legacy BIOS or UEFI BIOS)

Need your help!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: go to BIOS by pressing F2 (from the manual of your laptop) button when you turn on the system and see the booting mode BIOS or UEFI. Updating the BIOS is good if you have not yet updated. Install the Ubuntu 18.04 in the same mode as of your windows 10 Installed. Dual booting will not effect windows10 but after successful installation of Ubuntu 18.04 you have to select windows10 from GRUB menu Option

Comment: Recently I figured out that my windows is installed as **Legacy OS**, is it making difficult to install Ubuntu on the separate partition? If so, how to resolve this issue please help!

Comment: Ok, your windows is installed in Legacy mode. So you need to install Ubuntu 18.04 in Legacy mode to avoid complications. Have you tried Installing 18.04 in Legacy mode?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Can you please send me the procedure that will be helpful. Thank you

Comment: can you go to live session.. That is "try Ubuntu" option. Open "GParted" and attach a Pic here to proceed further.